# Android equivalent Google Places REST API Search

Tags: google-places-api

I can find a list of restaurant using below REST API.. Is there an Android equivalent API for this? OR I have to make these REST call from my android App and parse the XML (or JSON) results to use in the Android App...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=51.543071, 0.049958&radius=500&types=restaurant&name=taste&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0):

Not sure understand you question, but trying to give an answer: you have two choices

1. use the Google Play Services in your app and use the Google Places API - the "geo" package. It would be the "native" way.
   For this confer to : https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start
2. use the Google Places Web Services and parse the answer on your own as you described.
   For this confer to : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro

hope this helps. let us know.

Comment: I think @user2232357 is having the same issue as I've come across. The Google Places API only seems to expose a method of searching using autocomplete, rather than searching just by type. You can search by type using the nearbysearch endpoint of the Web Services API, but they were asking how to do it using the Google Places API in an Android app. As far as I can tell, there's no current way to search by type with the native Places API, so it looks like you need to stick with the Web Services API for now.